# Expresiones regulares, mostrar exactamente números que contengan 3 cifras

Tags: python, regex

Un muy buen lunes para todos.
Lo que quiero obtener es lo siguiente, teniendo estos 5 números “316 4128 12 2174 223” que solo encuentre “316 y 223” probé poniendo al final el signo $ y nada, espero deseen ayudarme, presiento que debe ser muy poco lo que me falta pero no lo logro, desde ya muchas gracias.-

```
import re
    
cadena = """01 - Roberto Daniel Virgili Ber. E. Lopez 2179 Arequito CP 2183
            02 - Claudio Javier Scardino Jujuy 1315 Rosario CP 218
         """
    
patron = r"[\d]{3}"
    
res = re.findall(patron, cadena)
    
print(res)
```

Comment: te puede ser de ayuda la pagina de redex learn, aca se muestran todos los "parametros permitidos" dejo el link [aca](https://regexr.com/) y para complementar o probar lo que quieres lograr te dejo [este otro link](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

La expresión regular `\s(\d\d\d)\s` reconoce y captura cifras de tres digitos rodeadas por espacios en blanco, pero tiene problemas con cadenas como está: " 123 456 ". La expresión reconoce bien el primer valor (123), pero al hacerlo ha *consumido* parte de la cadena, y lo que queda para seguir trabajando es "456 ", que no será reconocido, pues no comienza con un espacio.

La expresión `\b(\d\d\d)\b` reconoce y captura cifras de tres digitos entre fronteras de palabra. El metacaracter `\b` reconoce una frontera de palabra, pero no la consume.

Una palabra es una secuencia ininterrupida de caracteres alfanumericos.

#### Demo

```
import re

tests = [
    "316 4128 12 2174 223",
    "316 412, 812° $217 223",
    "316 412 812 217 223",
    "01 - Roberto Daniel Virgili Ber. E. Lopez 2179 Arequito CP 2183",
    "02 - Claudio Javier Scardino Jujuy 1315 Rosario CP 218"
    ]

patron = r"\b(\d\d\d)\b"

for test in tests:
    res = re.findall(patron, test)
    print(test, res)
```

produce:

```
316 4128 12 2174 223 ['316', '223']
316 412, 812° $217 223 ['316', '412', '812', '217', '223']
316 412 812 217 223 ['316', '412', '812', '217', '223']
01 - Roberto Daniel Virgili Ber. E. Lopez 2179 Arequito CP 2183 []
02 - Claudio Javier Scardino Jujuy 1315 Rosario CP 218 ['218']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hola, gracias x tu invalorable aporte, mucho me temo no poder interpretar del todo tu posteo, hace 1 mes que inicie con Python, gracias.-

Comment: Hola, @Candid Moe después de leer tu código me di cuenta que era la solución tal vez un poco avanzado para mis limitados conocimientos.-
Te dejo el código hecho a mi manera y me queda una duda (que seguramente esta la respuesta en tu código pero no la encuentro) ¿Por qué esta es la única manera que falla?

tests = "316a 4128 12 2174 223 3168 412, 812° $217 223"  
¿se entiende?, cuando se pone una letra pegada a la derecha del número. 
import re

tests = "316 4128 12 2174 223 3168 412, 812° $217 223"

patron = r"\b(\d\d\d)\b"

res = re.findall(patron, tests)

print(res)

Comment: @Daniel1952. El metacaracter '\b' reconoce un **frontera de palabra**. O sea, algo alfanumerico (a-z0-9) junto a algo no alfanumérico. En el caso "316a", después del último dígito viene una letra, por lo tanto no es frontera y no el patrón no se reconoce.  No es una solución perfecta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más fácil, me parece, es ubicar todos los bloques numéricos y luego mediante una comprensión de listas quedarnos con aquellos cuya longitud sea 3:

```
patron = r"\d+"
    
res = re.findall(patron, cadena)
    
print([num for num in res if len(num) == 3])
```

En realidad con expresiones regulares es posible resolverlo, usando el patrón de separador de palabra, esperando que los tres números estén rodeados de separadores de palabra:

```
patron = r"\b\d{3}\b"
```

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias x el aporte, me quedo con tu sugerencia con una pequeña modificación para tener el resultado en una nueva lista, gracias.-